# How to change code/repository from fabric v1 to v2?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

What can I do, when a repository is done for hyperledger fabric v. 1 and I wanna adapt it to hyperledger fabric v. 2.0?

Where and how do I need to make changes?
(The binaries are for fabric v 2.0)

I tried something but it is completly a mess, due to I just started with programming...

Let's take for example [this](https://github.com/sakshm-aurora/fabric-samples) repository.

Am very thankful for every suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Use the updated fabric images for Peers, Orderers, and Fabric CA.

Comment: Thanks @Aditya Joshi. The images are updated. What about the chaincode? Do I need to change anything there?